# flash editor slows down more code I write

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have flash cs4 and when I am typing code in the editor. It appears that the more code I add to my .as document, the more sluggish it gets. When typing, it appears to be a delay for when my text actually appears on screen. does anyone know what this could be.

My computer is not even a year old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue in the original Flash CS4 shipment. Adobe has release the update to fix the issue in their [official site](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/downloads.html).

As Allan stated, FlashDevelop can save your time alot by using its code-completion feature. The time you can save is probably more than if you can write code in the original AS editor with no lag.

In response for numerical25: I'm not sure if these can help, never tried though, but it might worth to try.

- Go to property window, edit profile > actionscript settings > uncheck the "Automatically declare stage instances". Basically it tell the compiler to not give your controller instance a name automatically during compile-time. But you need to declare a name manually in your class
- or you might want to try using [embed] tag :)

Answer (score 2):

The best advice I could offer would be to move away from using CS4 ide for coding. Take a look at FlashDevelop. It is a free, small download. It will allow you to organize your code better, provide code hinting and much more. You will never look back.

EDIT: There is also FDT which I think is the best but it cost $$$

Comment: I have tried flashDevelop, and I do indeed love it. My only problem is I couldnt get controllers (button class and other interface libraries) to work for the life of me. So I back away. However I do like it way more then flash cs4. I just couldnt get that to work.

Comment: I think I might do my next project in flash develop however.

Comment: yes, probably not the best idea to interrupt your current project. If you get stuck with flash develop I am sure you can post either here or on flash develop to sort stuff out :)

Comment: I wish they had a Mac version of Flash Develop :( but Flash Develop is a very nice coder for ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is simply a badly implemented editor.

Comment: It really does seem like adobe hired a bunch of people to work on the Flash IDE that don't have a good grip on efficient algorithms or data structures. I also know that flash slows to a crawl if you have nesting in the movie about 7 layers deep.

Answer (score 1):

(In response to Allan's answer) 
You can also use FlashDevelop as an external editor only, and still use Flash CS4 to publish and run it all. That way you would gain the benefit of a speedy ActionScript editor, and not lose your existing setup.

But maybe it would be a good idea to try and make your scripts a little smaller? Separate them into smaller classes...

Comment: +1. just use the "Flash IDE Project"-template ... i think f5 or something like that will simply switch to Flash IDE and compile the current fla ...